# Categorizing label customization in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I need to set different font sizes and different colours for my text strings, which appear in QGIS 3.x labels.

I found a solution at [Setting different colors based on value when labeling using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217436/qgis-when-labeling-how-can-i-set-different-colors-based-on-the-value) but it doesn't work in my case.

In my data attribute table, which looks like below:

[image]

I used the "text" column to define my label.

Now, I want to distinguish some strings, making them bigger (font size) and red instead of black.

Basing on the solution from the link above I prepared the simple function:
"color24" = 1

unfortunately, along with the red color, I am getting the "1" value.

In the other case, when my function looks like:

```
  CASE
  WHEN "Text" like '%GW%' then color_rgb (255, 0, 0)
  END
```

I am getting nothing.

[image]

Is anyone able to help with this?
I need to know how to change the font size and the font color on a categorized basis.

---

After the function:

```
   CASE When "Color24" = 1 Then color_rgb(255,0,0)
   end
```

and other settings, as seen in the image below...

[image]

gives the answer, but eventually, the result doesn't work properly.
Mainly only 1 of 3 labels are changed. They shift between older settings and new one as the zoom level changes.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: I'd go for `data defined override` instead of rule based labelling. Also, try removing the space between `color_rgb` and the `(`. Also, it is rather unclear what you set where.

Comment: I don't know the data defined override

Comment: To the right of almost every field in QGIS, where you can enter a value, there's two stacked rectangles with two smaller triangles attached to them. If you click there, you may either choose a column which holds valid values to override the settings for this field, or enter an expression which does the same.

Comment: See this answer for an example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370986/making-colours-from-table-with-colour-percentages-rgb-codes/370989#370989

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'data defined override' option for 'Size' in the Labels tab of Layer Styling - you won't need rule based labelling:

[image]

In my example here, there's a basic point layer with two categories, 'house' and 'car'.

[image]

To style them differently, you click on the data-defined-override drop-down and select 'edit', then add an expression to produce the numbers for each font size:

```
CASE  
    WHEN "category" = 'House' THEN 14.0
    WHEN "category" = 'Car' THEN 20.0
END
```

[image]

Note - for simplicity you could also just have a column called "font_size" and use that as the expression!