# QGIS 3x setting scale-based label color

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to have a different color for my label when zooming out.

I've prepared an expression, which is not valid

```
 CASE 
 if(@map_scale>1750, (color rgb 128,128,128))
 else
 "auxiliary_storage_labeling_color"
 end
```

There is a good example here:

[Setting different colors based on value when labeling using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217436/setting-different-colors-based-on-value-when-labeling-using-qgis)

but applies to the certain data attribute table feature.
How to write a scale-based expression?
What have I done wrong in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax for your expression is:

```
if(@map_scale>1750,color_rgb(128,128,128),"auxiliary_storage_labeling_color")
```

or

```
Case
When @map_scale>1750 Then color_rgb(128,128,128)
Else "auxiliary_storage_labeling_color"
End
```